# JavaFX: How to center the center node on a borderpane according to the Stage?

Tags: java, javafx, borderpane

I am having a problem centering a button in my borderpane to be centered according to the stage. It is centered according to the borderpane but I want it to be in the exact center of the window.

[image]

I am referring to the bottom part of my picture which has the play button and difficulty choiceBox.

I am using a borderpane to have the difficulty part be on the right side and the play button in the center.

As you can see, play is not centered in the picture.

I would like to do that but I'm not sure how. I think that I could possibly set the width of my left node to be equal to my right node but I don't have anything for my left Node.

```
// bottom section for positioning
    BorderPane settings = new BorderPane();
    settings.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    // play button
    Button playBtn = new Button("Play");
    settings.setCenter(playBtn);

    // difficulty options
    Label diffLabel = new Label("Difficulty: ");
    ChoiceBox<String> diffBox = new ChoiceBox<String>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Easy", "Standard", "Hard"
    ));
    diffBox.getSelectionModel().select(1);

    // for wrapping the diffuclty.
    HBox difficulty = new HBox(diffLabel, diffBox);
    difficulty.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    difficulty.setSpacing(10);

    settings.setRight(difficulty);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the possibilities is to add a `Region` to the left side of the `BorderPane` to act like a spacer.

From the [doc of `BorderPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html):

> The left and right children will be resized to their preferred widths
>   and extend the length between the top and bottom nodes. And the center
>   node will be resized to fill the available space in the middle.

Therefore adding a spacer with the same width as the `HBox` on the right side should solve the problem:

```
Region padderRegion = new Region();
padderRegion.prefWidthProperty().bind(difficulty.widthProperty());
settings.setLeft(padderRegion);
```

Here the width of the left spacer is bound to the width of the `HBox` on the right side, therefore the centered `Node` (the play button) will be centered on the screen.

Another possibility is to use various padders within a `HBox`:

```
HBox bottomPanel = new HBox();
bottomPanel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

Region padderRegion1 = new Region();
Region padderRegion2 = new Region();
Region padderRegion3 = new Region();
padderRegion1.prefWidthProperty().bind(diffLabel.widthProperty().add(diffBox.widthProperty()));

bottomPanel.getChildren().addAll(padderRegion1, padderRegion2, playBtn, padderRegion3, diffLabel, diffBox);
HBox.setHgrow(padderRegion2, Priority.ALWAYS);
HBox.setHgrow(padderRegion3, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually works perfectly. I tried doing this with an AnchorPane but it didn't work. Guess I needed to use a Region. It also doesn't make the bottom section wider than the top section which the other solution did.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {

        BorderPane settings = new BorderPane();
        settings.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Button playBtn = new Button("Play");

        Label zombieLabel = new Label("Zombie Dice");
        zombieLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 60");
        zombieLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox zomBox = new HBox();
        zomBox.getChildren().add(zombieLabel);
        zomBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label indicateLabel = new Label("Indicate who is playing");
        indicateLabel.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 20");
        indicateLabel.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox indBox = new HBox();
        indBox.getChildren().add(indicateLabel);
        indBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


        ChoiceBox<String> diffBox = new ChoiceBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Easy", "Standard", "Hard"
        ));
        diffBox.getSelectionModel().select(1);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);

        ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints(150);
        ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints(150);
        ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints(150);

        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1, col2, col3);
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(playBtn);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        gridPane.add(zomBox, 0, 0, 3, 1);
        gridPane.add(indBox, 0, 1, 3, 1);
        gridPane.add(hBox, 1, 2);
        gridPane.add(diffBox, 2, 2);

        Scene root = new Scene(gridPane);
        stage.setScene(root);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

probably you have to play with padding and gap.

Comment: Ok this works, however I was wondering if there is a way to make it so that you don't hardcode the column constraints. Also I did some modifications and found that if I make the middle Column Constraint smaller, it won't stretch the window and make the bottom more wide than top, however at the same time if I make it too small, the play button will not display "play" but an ellipsis instead. Is there a way to fix this and still make it as small as possible?